# How to switch to another branch in Git just after clone?

Tags: git, branch

I have a repository with many brunches and I cloned it.

```
git clone myproject
cd myproject
```

Now I wish to switch to branch, other than `master`.

How should I do this?

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

doesn't work, it creates new branch with given name instead.

Comment: `git checkout mybranch`

Comment: This is one of the fundamental git commands. Surely you could have found the answer you needed by a quick search?

Comment: Git is supposed to make life easier .. But instead it forces us to learn the tool and makes life complicated.   Why the hell on the earth I should checkout the whole repository rather than just checking out a specific branch..

Comment: And GIT came up with multiple version of commands with same functionality to cover up the design mistakes  and its naming conventions are too messy and ambiguous.   Lot of people simply do "rm -rf"  and checkout fresh copy if something is messed up in GIT.

Comment: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-d28f46654cd788d9c8e29a04bf1bf2f2.webp   This sums up the whole GIT